# In Azure DevOps Pipelines, how can I examine the directory structure of an agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a task to run unit tests after a build, but I can't figure out what to enter for the "Test files" field. It would be nice if I could get a directory listing of the agent so I can see where the test DLL is. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cant really do that native, there was an third party extension for that, but tbh its easier to just insert a step that does:

```
ls -Rla
```

and examine the output

Comment: Thanks! This is a Windows machine so I used `dir /s` instead; looks like there are no files to be found. I wonder how I get a copy of my build artifacts onto the file system?

Comment: there is a download build artifacts step you can use specifically for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you using a linux agent, [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69447793/1977871) answer may help.

And for windows agent, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58313988/1977871) in the same SO question above.