# Azure DevOps pipeline artifact displays this error: "No version is available for PlatformV2 Build..."

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Full error:

> No version is available for PlatformV2 Build or the latest version has no artifacts to publish. This might fail deployment. Please check the source pipeline.

I checked the "PlatformV2 Build" and I see that there have been many successful builds. Why are they not appearing as artifacts? I'm assuming this is why I am running into [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203467/in-azure-devops-pipelines-how-can-i-examine-the-directory-structure-of-an-agent/57203510?noredirect=1#comment100914979_57203510) with the directory structure on the agent being empty.

Comment: i am sorry but i have no idea what you are trying to do. can you pls explain what you are trying to do. Is your problem that your builds don't generate artifacts or that the artifacts don't get picked up ?

Comment: I don't know if the artifacts are being generated or not; I'm not that familiar with pipelines. What I'm trying to do is create a pipeline to take the latest build and run any unit tests that it contains. But the unit test task fails because the test DLL is missing.

Comment: then check your build first. you can see on the summary of the last build if there are any artifacts present. There should be a dropdown in the top right of that summary

Comment: Hmm, I can't find any artifacts dropdown - can you share a screenshot, please?

Comment: Should look like this -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpfaqre3yyqh2l1/ADO_build_artifactsDropdown.png?dl=0

Comment: If you don't see a dropdown there then you don't create artifacts with your build

Comment: Oh, thanks! So I don't see that menu - how do I cause artifacts to be created with a build, then? I wonder though - maybe I need to just have the unit tests run as part of the build itself rather than the release?

Comment: you can upload created assemblies or whatever you want to reuse as artifact with the task "Publish Build Artifact".just add it to the end of your build and point to whatever you want to use as artifact

Comment: I finally figured out the "Publish Build Artifact" as well but I'm still being told that no version is available so I'm totally lost about the versioning part. I do see versions in other places but it's just slightly confusing and I don't know why I'm being told no version available.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy and publish something first from your pipeline first. The following tasks in your YML will publish the entire content of the target directory from your project (where 'target' is the destination directory of an earlier task in your pipeline).

(You can remove the condition. It is there only to avoid publishing artifacts from pull requests. This pipeline is also triggered on branch changes so it has logic to handle both)

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/target'
    Contents: '**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    CleanTargetFolder: true
    OverWrite: true
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'SpringFramework_fullsources'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
  condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
```